# WPF show series of image use ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is my XAML I want to show series of image use DataTempalte in ItemsControl,
when I run the program the screen show only one image. I can't find what's wrong with it.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl Width="1024" Height="658" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSet}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1024" Height="658" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="rectangle" Source="{Binding Img}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Can anybody help me to find out, appreciate!

Comment: What is the purpose of the `StackPanel` in the `DataTemplate`? Are you trying to scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, correct me if I am wrong, but I think you are trying to scroll horizontally through your pictures. You have your `ScrollViewer` set to scroll horizontally but the `ItemsControl` inside does not have a horizontal orientation by default. This is why you are only seeing one picture. Try changing the default `ItemsPanel` and see if you get better results. Something like this:

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ItemsControl Width="1024"
                  Height="658"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSet}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Image Source="{Binding Img}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

This was a great resource for me when I was first trying to understand the `ItemsControl` in WPF: http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/